# How does OpenGL compute shader threads map to warps?

Tags: opengl, compute-shader

In CUDA, threads with id 0-31, 32-63, ... always execute in the same warp. However, I can't find any similar statement in OpenGL spec or wiki. Does OpenGL provide the same guarantee, or is it safe to assume that for most OpenGL implementations?

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL spec does not say anything about warps, which are nVidia specific implementation detail.

In OpenGL parlance the *shader invocations* are divided into *workgroups*. The number of shader invocations in a workgroup is specified by the `layout(local_size_x = X​, local_size_y = Y​, local_size_z = Z​) in;` declaration in the shader. The number of workgroups is specified in the `glDispatchCompute` call. The way they are mapped into CUDA warps is an implementation detail *which is transparent to you as a user*.

Comment: As long as performance is concerned, this is not truly transparent. A change in warp division may cause up to 32x slow in shared memory access (on NVIDIA and AMD hardware)

Comment: @HuazuoGao: Yes, it might. But the OpenGL specification doesn't let you know about any of that. The specification is an *abstraction*.

Comment: @HuazuoGao: True, but it is reasonable to assume that the implementation will allocate the hardware resources in the most efficient way. Note that you don't really care for the exact thread-id ↔ warp mapping, only that they aren't wasted.

Comment: I understand OpenGL as a spec cannot mandate that. On the other hand, if most vendors implement OpenGL in such a way, it would be quite helpful for optimization.

Answer (score 1):

For ARM-based GPUs (in phones) like Mali, you do not have warps. Rather, every core goes the whole pixel pipeline. Read this
https://community.arm.com/groups/arm-mali-graphics/blog/2014/04/23/arm-mali-compute-architecture-fundamentals